# Converting 24hours time format to 12hours for slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was having some problem when trying to convert 24 hours format time into 12 hours format on my slider bar. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/) . As you can see, when you try to slide in one way from AM to PM, it was working perfectly.

However, once it reached PM and you slide back to AM, it just appeared as PM all the way. I could not modified the value by the slider bar as I have some database depending on it. The only part that I can modify is where I try to display it at the sliderValue which is this part:

```
// Convert 24 hours format into 12
        if(hours == 0){
            hours = 12;
            ext = "AM";
        }
        if(hours == 12){
            ext = "PM";
        }
        if(hours > 12){
            hours = hours - 12;
            ext = 'PM';
        }

        $('#sliderValue').html(hours+':'+minutes + ext);
```

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never check the other way around. http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/4/

Comment: I see I see. Would you mind to post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never checked the other way around, you need to do it like so:

```
// Convert 24 hours format into 12
if(hours < 12)
{
    ext = 'AM';

    if(hours == 0)
    {
        hours = 12;
    }
}

else
{
    ext = 'PM';   

    if(hours > 12)
    {
         hours -= 12;   
    }
}
```

http://prntscr.com/5qmrs7

Answer (score 1):

Why change the value of hours in your routine? 
Use a separate value like

```
var americanTime = hours;
if(hours > 12) {
  americanTime = hours - 12;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/)

```
   $(function() {
    var ext = 'AM';
    $('#sliderValue').html('12:00AM');
    $("#slider-range").slider({       
    min: 0,
    max: 1380,
    step: 60,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
        var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
        var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

        if(hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
        if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;
        if(minutes==0)minutes = '00';

        // Convert 24 hours format into 12


        if(hours >= 12){
            ext = 'PM';
        }
        else{
            ext = 'AM';
        }

        if(hours>12){
            hours = hours - 12;
        }

        $('#sliderValue').html(hours+':'+minutes + ext);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0twk5L7y/5/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#sliderValue').html('12:00AM');
    $("#slider-range").slider({       
        min: 0,
        max: 1380,
        step: 60,
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            var ext = 'AM';
            var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
            if(hours > 12){
                ext = 'PM';
            }
            var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);
            if(hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
            if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;
            if(minutes==0)minutes = '00';

            // Convert 24 hours format into 12
            if(hours == 0){
                hours = 12;
            }
            $('#sliderValue').html(hours+':'+minutes + ext);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You never specify the AM suffix for hours that are between 0 and 12. So when your slider comes back from the PM section, it never gets updated and stays as PM (until you drop it back to 0, at least).

Add the section

```
if(hours > 0 && hours < 12){
      ext = 'AM';
}
```

And you should get your expected result.